# Teste de requisições assíncronas

Tags: ios, testes, objective-c

Como eu posso fazer requisições assíncronas nos TestCases do iOS? Exemplo:

```obj-c
-(void)test
{
    UserModel* user = [UserModel sharedInstance];
    [user requestUserInformationWithCompletion:^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* info){
        if(error)
        {
            STAssertTrue(error == nil, @"Erro no resultado");
        }else
        {
            STAssertTrue([[info objectForKey@"Nome"] isEqualToString:user.name], @"Usuário inválido");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Essa solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5847/8507) não é a melhor. Embora no teu caso, onde só estas a executar testes, sirva.

Tomei a iniciativa de interpretar a pergunta como uma questão de concorrência geral, onde uma thread tem de esperar por outra. Assim, ficas alertado para quando necessitares de implementas um sistema semelhante num ambiente sério.

---

A ideia está correcta, o que se quer é 'travar' a thread. No entanto, quando o run loop executar esse ciclo while estará a gastar tempo que poderia usar com outra thread.

Uma solução preferível será usar uma variável de condição. Isso pode ser feito com uma instância de [NSCondition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html).

O código abaixo adormece a thread até a chamada assíncrona terminar. Ao contrário da tua solução, aqui a thread 'travada' não executa até estar desbloqueada.

```
- (void) test
{
    // 1
    NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition new];
    [condition lock];
    // 2
    UserModel* user = [UserModel sharedInstance];
    [user requestUserInformationWithCompletion:^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* info){
        if(error) {
            STFail(@"Erro no resultado: %@",error.debugDescription);
        } else {
            STAssertTrue([[info objectForKey@"Nome"] isEqualToString:user.name], @"Usuário inválido");
        }
        [condition lock];
        [condition signal]; // 5
        [condition unlock];
    }];
    // 3
    double timeout = 10.0;
    dispatch_time_t timeout_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(timeout_time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [condition lock];
        [condition signal]; // 5
        [condition unlock];
    });
    // 4
    [condition wait];
    [condition unlock];
    STAssertTrue(!bloqueado, @"O teste terminou por time out");
}
```

Uma explicação breve ao código:

1. Criar a variável de condição.
2. Iniciar a chamada assíncrona.
3. Iniciar um timer para o *timeout*.
4. Adormecer a thread até receber um sinal (5).
5. Sinalizar a thread adormecida para voltar a executar. Não há problema em sinalizar uma condição que não tenha threads à espera.

## Atenção

Para este problema em particular, a solução não é de todo relevante. E o uso de um while serve.

Com esta resposta, só quero alertar que **esse ciclo while está a consumir ciclos de processamento** que poderiam ser usados para outro tipo de computações. Como tal, pode afectar resultados de análise, por exemplo.

Se a memória não me falha, o que gasta ciclos de processamento nesse while:
 - Verificar o valor da variável `bloqueado`; na linguagem máquina é ver se o valor apontado por um endereço de memória é diferente ou igual a zero.
 - Verificar o valor da variável `contador`; por um lado, é menos mau que `bloqueado` pois a optimização do compilador irá resultar nessa variável ficar em registo, no entanto, é mais complicado verificar valores de números não inteiros.
 - Fazer uma série de *calls* aos métodos `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:`, `runMode:beforeDate:` e `currentRunLoop`; isto é um pouco mais complicado do que parece, pois em Objective-C o programador não chama métodos, o programador envia mensagens; em run-time, o sistema irá ter que traduzir essas mensagens em chamadas de métodos e só depois chamá-los. (Este conceito de enviar mensagens é o que dá poder às Cocoa e Cocoa-Touch, pesquisa um pouco por [*method swizzling*](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) e [*key-value observing*](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) para perceberes algumas das ramificações.)
 - Incrementar o valor da variável `contador`.

E isso é só o que o teu código faz; existe ainda o que o sistema faz por ti.

---

Aconselho também que dês uma leitura ao [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) por três motivos:

1. Posso não ter explicado correctamente; tenho uma ideia geral de como isso funciona, mas não sei os detalhes de cor.
2. Esta pode também não ser a melhor solução; se em vez de responder a um POST estivesse a desenvolver, iria reler o guia e estudar qual a melhor solução. A melhor solução para um problema pode não ser a melhor para outro.
3. Na minha opinião, é de extrema importância compreender como a plataforma gere a execução das várias threads, e que mecanismos existêm para resolver questões de concorrência; não como a que apresentas na pergunta, mas outras onde é imprescindível encontrar a solução mais eficiente.

Espero ter sido informativo, e que esta resposta te ajude no futuro ;)

---

## Update

Baseado no comentário de Bavarious, apresento uma melhoria:

```
- (void) test
{
    CFRunLoopRef runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();

    UserModel* user = [UserModel sharedInstance];
    [user requestUserInformationWithCompletion:^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* info){
        if(error) {
            STFail(@"Erro no resultado: %@",error.debugDescription);
        } else {
            STAssertTrue([[info objectForKey@"Nome"] isEqualToString:user.name], @"Usuário inválido");
        }
        CFRunLoopStop(runLoop);
    }];

    double timeout = 10.0;
    dispatch_time_t timeout_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(timeout_time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        CFRunLoopStop(runLoop);
    });

    CFRunLoopRun();
    STAssertTrue(!bloqueado, @"O teste terminou por time out");
}
```

Isto é uma grande melhoria, pois permite que os blocos possam ser executados pela mesma thread que executa a função. Tal não é possível com a solução original desta resposta.

Admito que não li a documentação com detalhe, mas pelo que percebi a solução de Bavarious não adormece a thread, mas "bloqueia" a execução. O que isto quer dizer é, o contexto de execução é "adormecido" e a thread é deixada a executar outros contextos. É semelhante à solução do Igor, pois o run loop continua a correr, mas o sistema trata de não executar o contexto que está "adormecido".

Mais informação na [documentação da Apple do CFRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html).

**Obrigado Bavarious.**

Comment: Uma sugestão para melhorar sua resposta: em vez de usar `NSCondition`, você poderia apenas chamar `CFRunLoopRun()` no item 4. Essa função roda o run loop indefinidamente. Para que o run loop seja interrompido quando o bloco for executado ou o timeout ocorrer (item 5), chame `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())`. O código fica mais simples.

Comment: @Bavarious Obrigado pela chamada de atenção. Já actualizei a resposta ;)

Comment: @rtiago42 Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Eu encontrei como fazer para forçar um teste a manter sua *thread* rodando e fazer requisições assíncronas no **OCTestCase**

Basicamente, é forçar o "travamento" da *thread* através de um **RunLoop** e liberá-lo após a resposta assíncrona, ou ao disparo de um *timeout*. Assim, a thread de teste é retida e o teste só é dado como sucesso ou falha depois que ocorra um *timeout* ou haja uma resposta.

Usando o mesmo código da pergunta como exemplo:

```obj-c
- (void) test
{
    __block BOOL bloqueado = YES;
    CGFloat contador = 0.0f;

    UserModel* user = [UserModel sharedInstance];
    [user requestUserInformationWithCompletion:^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* info) {
        if(error) {
            STFail(@"Erro no resultado: %@",error.debugDescription);
        } else {
            STAssertTrue([[info objectForKey@"Nome"] isEqualToString:user.name], @"Usuário inválido");
        }
        bloqueado = NO;
    }];

    while(bloqueado && contador < 10.0f) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
        contador += 0.1f;
    };

    STAssertTrue(!bloqueado,@"O teste terminou por time out");
}
```